# Can we include custom sql scripts to run in Airflow deployment?

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I am trying to run a airflow job to perform some SQL operations on Snowflake instance using MWAA(managed Airflow from AWS). While setting up the Airflow in MWAA its asks for DAG, plugin and requirements. Is there any way to include custom sql scripts?

Below is the example that I have tried:

```
with DAG(
    'Snowflake_Prototype',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    template_searchpath="include"
) as dag:

    start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
    
    t2 = SnowflakeOperator(
            task_id='create_staging_tables',
            snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID,
            sql='create_staging.sql'
        )
```

I am planning to run sql command in creating_staging.sql. For which, I have uploaded sql script "create_staging.sql" to a folder called include in s3 and then referenced it airflow via template_searchpath in DAG declaration. Looks like its not airflow is not importing all the contents of the s3. It does not seem to locate the file. Is there any other way to include the relevant scripts when running airflow via MWAA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to the `create_staging.sql` like that - with relative reference, I think it should be placed next to the dag itself, not in a dedicated "include" folder. So just place it in the same directory where you place your dags.

Alternatively you might try to find the full path of where the "include" folder is mounted eventually in MWAA worker and use full "absolute" path.

Comment: Thanks Jarek. MWAA seems to pick up the .sql file when placed in DAG folder. It looks like MWAA only includes files from plugins, requirements and DAG folder and  ignores anything else from the s3 bucket. In this case it has not included "include" folder.

Comment: Actually you can create a folder in the MWAA environment and download file from S3.You can place your files in the folder created

Answer (score 0):

You can add the files by providing template_searchpath as mentioned below.
template_searchpath='/usr/local/airflow/dags/[ your base folder which includes sql].

Ex: /usr/local/airflow/dags/load/sql/